# compatibility problem between FEniCS and Paraview on Mac

Tags: docker, paraview, fenics

I am using FEniCS on mac trough Docker but I have a problem visualizing the result of an analysis using a Paraview version installed on mac. These are the steps I follow:
I obtain the solution of my problem using FEniCS; then send the .vtu file that FEniCS has generated from Docker to the desktop using

```
sudo docker cp fenics-container:/home/fenics/shared/nameoffile.vtu Users/User/Desktop
```

Subsequently, I open ParaView (which I directly installed on my mac and not on Docker) and open the file `nameoffile.vtu`. I press `Apply` and then an error appears:

`ERROR: In /Users/kitware/dashboards/buildbot-slave/a64f5607/build/superbuild/paraview/src/VTK/IO/XML/vtkXMLUnstructuredDataReader.cxx, line 649
vtkXMLUnstructuredGridReader (0x7fc30ff7c440): Error reading cell offsets: Unsupported array type: vtkUnsignedIntArray`

Can anyone explain what this error means?

when I tried open the file using Paraview on a Linux machine it worked just fine with no error. Am I missing some compatibility package?

Comment: More a question for https://discourse.paraview.org/ imo.

Comment: I was able to reproduce this problem running Fenics on Linux, outside of a docker container. I then opened the simulation files in Windows. It doesn't seem specific to mac.

Answer (score 1):

Solved.
I installed a previous version of ParaView. Apparently latest ones are not fully compatible with all versions of FEniCS

Comment: Paraview 5.7.0 worked for me, see [this discourse topic](https://fenicsproject.discourse.group/t/error-in-opening-3d-plots-in-fenics-and-pvd-files-in-paraview-5-8-0-in-ubuntu-19-04/2442/2), it might also be fixed in Paraview 5.8.1.